# Markdown not compiling after first Chunk (stoping when reaching html scrape)

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Markdown does not compile after the first chunk.  I am able to run all the chunk individually and run them all at once.  When attempting to Knit to a HTML document, markdown does not compile right at the first chunk and stops.  No Errors, No Warnings, etc., and just stops.

I have tried eval = False, which just outputs nothing, I removed several portions of the code and found it is the portion of the scrape of the HTML table.  However, works when I run the chunk.

````
---
title: "Harry Potter Cast"
author: "Ben Tanaka"
date: "5/29/2019"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
---


```{r setup, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE,message =FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(data.table)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

# *Harry Potter Cast*
```{r Harry_Potter}

potter_url <- 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_1'
potter_scrape <- read_html(potter_url)
potter_cast_uf <- {potter_scrape %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[3]] %>% html_table()}
potter_cast_df <- potter_cast_uf[,c(2,4)]

setnames(potter_cast_df,old=c("X2","X4"),new=c("Actor","Character"))
str_replace_all(potter_cast_df$Actor, '[\r\n]' , '')
str_replace_all(potter_cast_df$Character, '[\r\n]' , '')
potter_cast_tbl <- as_tibble(potter_cast_df)

{potter_cast_tbl %>% mutate_all(funs(str_replace_all(.,'[\r\n]' , '')))}
potter_cast_tbl <- potter_cast_tbl[-1,]
potter_cast_tbl <- potter_cast_tbl[-92,]
{potter_cast_tbl %>% mutate_all(funs(str_replace_all(.,'Griphook /  \n            Professor Filius Flitwick' , 'Griphook / Professor Filius Flitwick')))}

{potter_cast_tbl <- potter_cast_tbl %>% separate(Actor,c("Actor_FName","Actor_MName","Actor_LName"))}

potter_cast_tbl$Actor_FName[!is.na(potter_cast_tbl$Actor_LName)]<- paste(potter_cast_tbl$Actor_FName[!is.na(potter_cast_tbl$Actor_LName)],potter_cast_tbl$Actor_MName[!is.na(potter_cast_tbl$Actor_LName)],sep=" ")

potter_cast_tbl$Actor_LName[is.na(potter_cast_tbl$Actor_LName)] <- potter_cast_tbl$Actor_MName[is.na(potter_cast_tbl$Actor_LName)]

potter_cast_tbl<-potter_cast_tbl[,-2]

output_dt <- head(potter_cast_tbl,10)

{output_dt %>% kable() %>% kable_styling()}
```
````

No Error messages.  Just trying to get the markdown html knit output.

Comment: Can you post your code, witth chunks, and/or tell us exactly what you are doing? If I wrap your code in ```{r} ... ``` it runs and produces output for me.

Comment: Since you said it worked I download R_Studio separately outside of Anaconda and it worked fine.  So I am not sure why it isn't working in Anaconda.  I will have to troubleshoot that later.  Thanks Jeremy for testing it out.